# Scanning for a XML tag and copying the whole content into another file till end tag is encountered

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a log file which will contain text logs as well as xml messages. The function should check for a particular xml tag. once encountered it should copy all the content of that xml message till the end tag is encountered into another file.
consider the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
obo.adapter :         Started processing the message
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
obo.crdadapter. :         stopped processing the message
```

The tag to scan is "catalog" so the output should be

```
<catalog>
     <book id="bk101">
          <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
          with XML.</description>
       </book>
 </catalog>
```

the simple approach is to do

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/app/log/log.txt"));
String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
   if(line.equalIgnoreCase("<tagName>")){
    //logic here
   }
}
in.close();
```

but is there a better way of achieving this? Please note the xml body might change so I cannot create a pojo of it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using regex pattern match. first loading the file into stringBuilder and then doing a pattern match over it. it works well for file size upto 72MB